# UINavigationItem rightButton position is different on iOS6 vs iOS7 and missing touches

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make my uinavigationbar to align the same way as in the iOS6 version of my app.  What I am finding is that on the iOS7 the uinavigationbar items are pulled in a bit towards the title.  Also for example if you are hitting just a litle right of the uinavigationitem.rightButton, the hits are not registered, however if you hit left of it for atleast 20px you can get the hits.  Can anyone help me with moving that touch area to the right as well?

Here is the code that I used to setup the button:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];

UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
rightButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0);
rightButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
rightButton.frame = view.bounds;
rightButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,44,44);
[view addSubview:rightButton];

[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithOpacity:0.8] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[rightButton addTarget:target action:sel forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

navItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
```

Thanks,
Rajan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
UIImage *faceImage1= [UIImage imageNamed:@"slideshowarrow"];
UIButton *face1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
face1.bounds = CGRectMake( 10, 0, faceImage1.size.width, faceImage1.size.height );
[face1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Goto_nextView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[face1 setImage:faceImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face1];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton1;
```

Comment: Thank you Pradhyuman.  This works, now only problem is that I still have the issue of how the button is displayed on the navbar, where on iOS the button is flushed all the way to the right side, whereas on iOS 7, there is about 20pix.  I can adjust that programmatically, but was wondering if Apple made that on purpose.